# how to avoid autosuggest by browser when the focus is on a field?

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm typing to disable/avoid the autosuggest on specific field.

The html snippet is this:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <h4 class="whitish" for="name-of-car-id">Name of car (max length 30 chars)</h4>
        <input type="input" class="form-control" placeholder="" id="name-of-car-id" autocomplete="off">
        <span id='remainingC'></span>
        <small class="form-text text-muted">You will identify your group of IDs by this name</small>
        <div id='name-of-car-error' style='color:red; font-size: 18px;'></div>
    </div>
```

note that I added the autocomplete='off' and yet, the browser still provide a suggestion.
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill

Comment: I have tried every possible solution on this tag - nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace input type="input" with type="text"